# Fabric.js getObjects() by tag or type

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

In fabric.js you can get all the lines in the canvas by using

```
objects = canvas.getObjects('line')
```

But I have some objects which are a group of **rect** and **text**.

How can I tag the items and get them as a group?
I cannot select all groups since there are other types of groups as well.

Here is my grouped object

```
var profilepic = new fabric.Rect({
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        fill: "#000",
        opacity: 0.7,
        strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
        stroke: '#fff',
        width: w,
        height: h
      });
      var text = new fabric.Text(text, {
        fontSize: 30,
        fill: "#fff",
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
      });
      var group = new fabric.Group([ profilepic, text ], {
        left: x,
        top: y,
        angle: 0,
      });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add any property you want to objects, so you can flag your group in some way

```
var group = new fabric.Group([profilepic, text], {
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  angle: 0,
  hasRectangle: true
});
```

And then I'm not sure how you were wanting to select your objects, but you can do something like this to get the ones you want:

```
let rectanglegroups = canvasobj._objects.filter(
  obj => obj.hasRectangle === true
);
rectanglegroups.map(obj => canvasobj.setActiveObject(obj));
```